# Search by user name in Sharepoint 2013 onpremises calendar

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-calendar

I have a SharePoint 2013 calendar, in which all users submitted their tasks. If a manager wants to see some specific user calendar by searching his name, how can he do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript workaround, which takes the current site, gets Calendar List ID, enumerates through List Roles and selects groups that contain the "Member" word.

- Place script editor web part on page with calendar view
- Copy and insert the code snippet below

**[CODE](https://www.pastebin.cz/raw/M9M31tq)**

Comment: How can I get id and name of your SharePoint group with the team members in it?